# The same asp.net mvc page for LDAP authenticated and anonymous users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap, authorization

I have some intranet  asp.net mvc3 app ,which is available for both LDAP authenticated and anonymous users.All of them are using IE. One of the views should be available for both of them, depending on status some columns should be hidden,etc.
I don't want anonymous users to receive popup authentication dialog,but can't see no way of solving problem.If I add `Authorize()` attribute ,it forces anonymous  user to input user/password, if I remove this attribute everyone is treated as anonymous.
How can be this obstacle solved?

Comment: Do you know the users sAMAccountName or similar identifier before they reach the view with the pop-up dialog?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller check to see if the user is authenticated and perform actions based off that conclusion.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
//Handle Case

}
```

Comment: No, if I remove Authorize() attribute it returns false for everyone.